# How to get back all settings of a Powershell task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm wanting to go through all my scheduled tasks to see which ones don't[image] have the option 'Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed' checked. Instead of doing this manual, I'm wanting to run a Powershell script to tell me which tasks, but can't seem to find the command to view this option. Please help?

Thank you!

Comment: `Get-Command -Name *task*`, `Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName Abe | select -ExpandProperty settings`.

Answer (score 0):

Get all scheduled tasks, loop through them, check if its settings `StartWhenAvailable` is false, then simply reveal the task name and location URI...

```
$tasks = Get-ScheduledTask
foreach ($task in $tasks) {
    if ($false -eq $task.Settings.StartWhenAvailable) {
        $task.URI
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer a single line:

```
$tasks | Select-Object -Property URI -ExpandProperty Settings | Where-Object -Property StartWhenAvailable -EQ -Value $False | Select-Object -Property URI
```

Comment: Thank you! I already knew how to get to the settings, but didn't know StartWhenAvailable was the option I needed to be looking for. That was very helpful.